# Importing rpy2 modules in Enthought Canopy python

Tags: python, r, rpy2, enthought

I reinstalled R and rpy2 after installing Enthought Canopy python.

In python I can now:

```
import rpy2
```

without an error message.
However, when I want to import any specific rpy2 modules, I get the following error:

```
import rpy2.robjects
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-bd461266c9bc> in <module>()
----> 1 import rpy2.robjects

/Users/martinkampmann/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.3.5-py2.7-macosx-10.6-i386.egg/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py in <module>()
     13 import itertools
     14 from datetime import datetime
---> 15 import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
     16 import rpy2.rlike.container as rlc
     17 

/Users/martinkampmann/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.3.5-py2.7-macosx-10.6-i386.egg/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py in <module>()
     99 
    100 
--> 101 from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import *
    102 
    103 

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/martinkampmann/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.3.5-py2.7-macosx-10.6-i386.egg/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so, 2): Symbol not found: _R_BaseEnv
  Referenced from: /Users/martinkampmann/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.3.5-py2.7-macosx-10.6-i386.egg/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/martinkampmann/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.3.5-py2.7-macosx-10.6-i386.egg/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so
```